# Deserialize a string in a generic List<> explodes with double quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

When attempting to retrieve and store a serialized list of data in local storage then subsequently sending to back to the server to be deserialized to it's original form, the process explodes when a string in the object contains an escaped double quote.

If the object is NOT in a collection (I've tried a List and ArrayObject), the code works fine.  What is it about a collection that causes grief?

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or suggest a better method to achieve the same result.  I came across this problem while trying to create an offline web application.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_default" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <div id="Feedback"></div>
            <div><a href="#" id="ExportButton">Export</a></div>
            <div><a href="#" id="ImportButton">Import</a></div>
        </form>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function Export() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'default.aspx/GetThings',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=u",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    var json = result.d;

                    $('#Feedback').html(json);

                    // failed attempt #1
                    //localStorage["things"] = json;

                    // failed attempt #2
                    var things = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                    localStorage["things"] = JSON.stringify(things);
                }
            });
        }

        function Import() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "default.aspx/PutThings",
                data: "{'json':'" + localStorage["things"] + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=u",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#Feedback').html(result.d);
                }
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#ExportButton").click(function () {
                Export();
            });

            $("#ImportButton").click(function () {
                Import();
            });
        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _default : Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetThings()
    {
        List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();

        Thing thing = new Thing();
        //thing.Description = "no escaped double quote string works fine";
        thing.Description = "100 (2 1/8\") Gear";
        things.Add(thing);

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

        serializer.Serialize(things, json);

        return json.ToString();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string PutThings(string json)
    {
        try
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            List<Thing> things = serializer.Deserialize<List<Thing>>(json);

            return things[0].Description;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }

    public class Thing
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: explodes = what? could you include the exception information

Comment: Is the return json.ToString() necessary? If you are using asp.net like your tags suggest, there are other (better) ways to return json. Try this first and see if your problem persists.

Comment: Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (29): [{"Description":"100 (2 1/8") Gear"}]

Comment: I tried using the more popular Json.NET to serialize/de-serialize instead of the native JavaScriptSerializer, sadly I get the exact same result.  Leads me to believe my code is the problem, not the serializers.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in the top of the `PutThings()` method, hope you have a good reason to serialise/deserialise manually rather then just [letting WCF take care of this for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When you've got the breakpoint you can take a look at the JSON string passed to the service and you'll be able to tell for yourself what kind of transform is needed to make it into a valid JSON string. I would guess that it's the build of the data string being sent to this function, as it looks like your placing quotes around the child JSON object string `localStorage["things"]`. The code should read..

```
data: "{'json':" + localStorage["things"] + "}",
```

If not, please post the JSON string being passed to your Put function and I'll be able to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: also, FYI, strictly speaking JSON uses double quotes rather then single quotes around parameters & field names.

Comment: This is what gets sent to the service:[{"Description":"100 (2 1/8") Gear"}]

Comment: The suggested data parameter code is invalid, the ajax call fails.

Comment: so the result of `JSON.stringify(things);` is `"100 (2 1/8") Gear"`? That doesn't seem right, the JSON should be valid because I can see your both deserialising and re-serialising which would throw an error if the JSON was invalid, also that string should be stored in a Description sub-property in an array. I spotted another mistake, `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(...)` returns the JSON string, `JavaScriptSerializer.ToString()` shouldn't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx